# Opaque and semi-transparent objects sharing the same shadow map?

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d

I'm implementing shadow maps for a scene where most of the objects are opaque and only a few objects (smoke particles) are semi-transparent. To accommodate this I added GL_R8 color buffer to traditional depth only texture, attached to the same FBO. This color buffer is supposed to be filled with 1.0f/255u when the shadows are cast by opaque objects and less than 1.0f then cast by smoke. For smoke particles I enabled blending so that overlapping particles produce more realistic view.

By now I have tried a few tricks such as: reordering the draw calls such that transparent shadow casters are processed first and changing depth testing function to GL_ALWAYS to enable blending. And it all works fine until two "kinds" of shadow should combine. Depending on whether or not particular trick is enabled I might generally get three kinds of artifact:

1. shadow from opaque caster closer to the light source gets overridden by semi-transparent shadow farther from the light source (where ideally the near part of the combined shadow should be 100% intense and the other farther part should be semi-transparent)
2. shadow from semi-transparent source closer to the light source makes shadow from the farther opaque object semi-transparent too. Where ideally near part of the shadow should be semi-transparent and farther part should be 100% intense.
3. The combination of 1) and 2)

All in all, I can't seem to find the combination of OpenGL state and draw order such that shadows look as they should. I realize that additional FBO for semi-transparent only objects would probably have solved all my issues, but the shadow map is occupying a lot of VRAM so I would like to skip making another one. So my question is if it's possible to keep opaque and non-opaque objects in the same shadow map (with intensity map) such that no visual artifacts are observed.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want no shadow until the semi-transparent object, then some half-shadowing until the opaque object and for everything after that full shadow? This will not be possible with a single shadow map. A shadow map can only store a single depth, but for your task, you'd need two depth values (start of half-shadow, start of full shadow).

Comment: You might to have a look at https://wickedengine.net/2018/01/18/easy-transparent-shadow-maps/ The basic idea is to have two shadow maps, one for transparent, one for non-transparent objects.

Comment: Yeah you got it right. I had hoped some clever trick with calls ordering and perhaps stencils could do the trick, but yeah you might be right, two shadow maps might be needed :(